# Get context directly in PagerAdapter?

Tags: java, android

I need to use `PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();` inside a PagerAdapter but I don't know how to get a context.

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
     ...
     }
```

How can context inside PagerAdapter?

Comment: Use a constructor like `MyPagerAdapter(Context ctx)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer of @DeeV means you must provide a context to your PageAdapter by yourself, either via the constructor or via a setter. Then store it inside the PageAdapter as a field and retrieve it whenever you need it.

Comment: Doesn't look like there is a natural way of doing so like in case of BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter using getContext(). You will have to follow what @Snicolas has mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

private ViewGroup _container;

```
public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
{
   _container = container;
}

private Context GetContext()
{
   return (Activity)_container.Context;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended provide Context, this may cause memory leaks, 
if you need the context to access resources, you can provide the resources through the constructor.

```
MyPagerAdapter(val resources: Resources){

}
....

val adapter = MyPagerAdapter(context.resources)
```